# Catkin_make Errors (multiple）

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am new to ROS. I am using Ubuntu 20.04, ROS Neotic Ninjemys in VMware workstation.
I am simply following a course in motion planning. just get started. And what i am asked to do:

Copy 3 folders (from course) to catkin_ws - src, one called 'grid_path_searcher', one called 'rviz_plugins', and the other one called 'waypoint_generator'

Delete Build and devel folder under catkin_ws, delete CmakeList.txt under catkin_ws - src

and then open up the terminal, enter the following code:

```
ls  'to see catkin_ws''
cd catkin_ws/ 'to enter it'
ls
cd src/ 'to enter it'
catkin_init_workspace     'to initialize it'
cd ..    'go back to previous folder'
catkin_make
```

then there are huge amount of codes jumped in my screen and I can barely copy all of them here. and the first few rows of code can not be scrolled up. looks like they terminal can only display certain amount of codes.
So I just picked up all the error messges here for your reference.

```
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h: In function ‘const pcl::PFHRGBSignature250& pcl::common::operator-=(pcl::PFHRGBSignature250&, const float&)’:
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:562:1: error: ‘minusscalar’ is not a member of ‘pcl::traits’
  562 | POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::PFHRGBSignature250,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h: In function ‘const pcl::PFHRGBSignature250& pcl::common::operator*=(pcl::PFHRGBSignature250&, const float&)’:
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:562:1: error: ‘mulscalar’ is not a member of ‘pcl::traits’
  562 | POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::PFHRGBSignature250,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h: In function ‘const pcl::PFHRGBSignature250& pcl::common::operator/=(pcl::PFHRGBSignature250&, const float&)’:
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:562:1: error: ‘divscalar’ is not a member of ‘pcl::traits’
  562 | POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::PFHRGBSignature250,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: ‘type’ is not a member of ‘pcl::traits::datatype<pcl::PPFSignature, pcl::fields::f1>::decomposed’ {aka ‘pcl::traits::decomposeArray<float>’}
  566 | POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::PPFSignature,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: ‘type’ is not a member of ‘pcl::traits::datatype<pcl::PPFSignature, pcl::fields::f1>::decomposed’ {aka ‘pcl::traits::decomposeArray<float>’}
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  566 | POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::PPFSignature,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: ‘type’ is not a member of ‘pcl::traits::datatype<pcl::PPFSignature, pcl::fields::f2>::decomposed’ {aka ‘pcl::traits::decomposeArray<float>’}
  566 | POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::PPFSignature,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: ‘type’ is not a member of ‘pcl::traits::datatype<pcl::PPFSignature, pcl::fields::f2>::decomposed’ {aka ‘pcl::traits::decomposeArray<float>’}
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  566 | POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::PPFSignature,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: ‘type’ is not a member of ‘pcl::traits::datatype<pcl::PPFSignature, pcl::fields::f3>::decomposed’ {aka ‘pcl::traits::decomposeArray<float>’}
  566 | POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::PPFSignature,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: ‘type’ is not a member of ‘pcl::traits::datatype<pcl::PPFSignature, pcl::fields::f3>::decomposed’ {aka ‘pcl::traits::decomposeArray<float>’}
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  566 | POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::PPFSignature,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: ‘type’ is not a member of ‘pcl::traits::datatype<pcl::PPFSignature, pcl::fields::f4>::decomposed’ {aka ‘pcl::traits::decomposeArray<float>’}
  566 | POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::PPFSignature,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: ‘type’ is not a member of ‘pcl::traits::datatype<pcl::PPFSignature, pcl::fields::f4>::decomposed’ {aka ‘pcl::traits::decomposeArray<float>’}
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  566 | POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::PPFSignature,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: ‘type’ is not a member of ‘pcl::traits::datatype<pcl::PPFSignature, pcl::fields::alpha_m>::decomposed’ {aka ‘pcl::traits::decomposeArray<float>’}
  566 | POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::PPFSignature,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: ‘type’ is not a member of ‘pcl::traits::datatype<pcl::PPFSignature, pcl::fields::alpha_m>::decomposed’ {aka ‘pcl::traits::decomposeArray<float>’}
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  566 | POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::PPFSignature,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:566:1: error: ‘plus’ is not a member of ‘pcl::traits’
  566 | POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::PPFSignature,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_types.h:588:1: error: ‘minus’ is not a member of ‘pcl::traits’
  588 | POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::PPFRGBSignature,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:108:38: error: ‘pcl::traits::HasNoXY’ has not been declared
  108 |   template <typename PointT, traits::HasNoXY<PointT> = true> constexpr inline bool
      |                                      ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:108:45: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token
  108 |   template <typename PointT, traits::HasNoXY<PointT> = true> constexpr inline bool
      |                                             ^
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:114:38: error: ‘pcl::traits::HasNoXYZ’ has not been declared
  114 |   template <typename PointT, traits::HasNoXYZ<PointT> = true> constexpr inline bool
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:114:46: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token
  114 |   template <typename PointT, traits::HasNoXYZ<PointT> = true> constexpr inline bool
      |                                              ^
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:120:38: error: ‘pcl::traits::HasNoNormal’ has not been declared
  120 |   template <typename PointT, traits::HasNoNormal<PointT> = true> constexpr inline bool
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:120:49: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token
  120 |   template <typename PointT, traits::HasNoNormal<PointT> = true> constexpr inline bool
      |                                                 ^
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:127:38: error: ‘pcl::traits::HasXY’ has not been declared
  127 |   template <typename PointT, traits::HasXY<PointT> = true> inline bool
      |                                      ^~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:127:43: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token
  127 |   template <typename PointT, traits::HasXY<PointT> = true> inline bool
      |                                           ^
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:128:3: error: redefinition of ‘template<class PointT, <typeprefixerror><anonymous> > bool pcl::isXYFinite(const PointT&)’
  128 |   isXYFinite (const PointT& pt) noexcept
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:109:3: note: ‘template<class PointT, <typeprefixerror><anonymous> > constexpr bool pcl::isXYFinite(const PointT&)’ previously declared here
  109 |   isXYFinite (const PointT&) noexcept
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:133:38: error: ‘pcl::traits::HasXYZ’ has not been declared
  133 |   template <typename PointT, traits::HasXYZ<PointT> = true> inline bool
      |                                      ^~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:133:44: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token
  133 |   template <typename PointT, traits::HasXYZ<PointT> = true> inline bool
      |                                            ^
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:134:3: error: redefinition of ‘template<class PointT, <typeprefixerror><anonymous> > bool pcl::isXYZFinite(const PointT&)’
  134 |   isXYZFinite (const PointT& pt) noexcept
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:115:3: note: ‘template<class PointT, <typeprefixerror><anonymous> > constexpr bool pcl::isXYZFinite(const PointT&)’ previously declared here
  115 |   isXYZFinite (const PointT&) noexcept
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:139:38: error: ‘pcl::traits::HasNormal’ has not been declared
  139 |   template <typename PointT, traits::HasNormal<PointT> = true> inline bool
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:139:47: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token
  139 |   template <typename PointT, traits::HasNormal<PointT> = true> inline bool
      |                                               ^
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:140:3: error: redefinition of ‘template<class PointT, <typeprefixerror><anonymous> > bool pcl::isNormalFinite(const PointT&)’
  140 |   isNormalFinite (const PointT& pt) noexcept
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/point_tests.h:121:3: note: ‘template<class PointT, <typeprefixerror><anonymous> > constexpr bool pcl::isNormalFinite(const PointT&)’ previously declared here
  121 |   isNormalFinite (const PointT&) noexcept
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~


/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_representation.h:308:7:   required from here
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_representation.h:252:48: error: the value of ‘NrDims’ is not usable in a constant expression
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_representation.h:251:19: note: ‘NrDims’ was not initialized with a constant expression
  251 |         const int NrDims = pcl::traits::datatype<PointDefault, Key>::size;
      |                   ^~~~~~
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/point_representation.h:252:48: note: in template argument for type ‘int’
  252 |         Helper<Key, FieldT, NrDims>::copyPoint (p1_, p2_, f_idx_);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [grid_path_searcher/CMakeFiles/random_complex.dir/build.make:63: grid_path_searcher/CMakeFiles/random_complex.dir/src/random_complex_generator.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:518: grid_path_searcher/CMakeFiles/random_complex.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

that's the end of catkin_make.

let me know if there are certain format that I need to follow. the forum instructions said I just need to copy and paste the source code here.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted]([https://answers.ros.org/question/372763/catkin_make-errors-(multiple）/)](https://answers.ros.org/question/372763/catkin_make-errors-(multiple%EF%BC%89/)) by [FreddyWang](https://answers.ros.org/users/70868/freddywang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-25**:\

> I am new to ROS. [..] I am simply following a course in motion planning.

have you asked the instructor(s) of the course?

Those should be your first point of contact.

**Comment by [FreddyWang](https://answers.ros.org/users/70868/freddywang/) on 2021-02-26**:
@Loguna @gvhoorn
Thanks!
I am not sure whether PCL library has been successfully configured in my Ubuntu system.
as I said, I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 in a VM. and I didn't remember that I used to configure any PCL related items. Should I go get PCL installed and configured first? any other library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would seems to me like your PCL library package is not properly configured in your PC.
That will explain why it cannot find certain types like Points.

Do know that Catkin_make is basically like a debug and build tool that debug and build all your ROS packages that contain inside that specific workspace.

---

Originally posted by [loguna](https://answers.ros.org/users/39943/loguna/) with karma: 98 on 2021-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1